# No result of tf.Print in keras's model.fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wrote that loss (for testing custom loss in keras):

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.log(y_pred))
  loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], 'loss = ')
return loss
```

and then:

```
model.compile(loss=loss, 
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

and there's no tf.Print results:

```
Epoch 1/12 
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s 198us/step - loss: 25.3197 - acc: 0.9384 - val_loss: 5.6927 - val_acc: 0.9857
Epoch 2/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 11s 187us/step - loss: 8.7803 - acc: 0.9798 - val_loss: 4.6938 - val_acc: 0.9888
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you're running this in Jupyter Notebook. [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) prints to the terminal *where the Jupyter Notebook was called from*. Take a look there and see if there's output.

See blue note at the [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) manual page.

From Evgeniya's comment below: you can write your own version of [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) to print the data you desire (code by [Vihari Piratla](https://gist.github.com/vihari/f9b361058825e16d390f0e443bfdffc7)):

```
"""
The default tf.Print op goes to STDERR
Use the function below to direct the output to stdout instead
Usage: 
> x=tf.ones([1, 2])
> y=tf.zeros([1, 3])
> p = x*x
> p = tf_print(p, [x, y], "hello")
> p.eval()
hello [[ 0.  0.]]
hello [[ 1.  1.]]
"""
def tf_print(op, tensors, message=None):
    def print_message(x):
        sys.stdout.write(message + " %s\n" % x)
        return x

    prints = [tf.py_func(print_message, [tensor], tensor.dtype) for tensor in tensors]
    with tf.control_dependencies(prints):
        op = tf.identity(op)
    return op
```

Comment: and there's no way to do it in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Are you in control of the Jupyter Notebook environment?

Comment: I found solution, needs to redirect stderr: https://gist.github.com/vihari/f9b361058825e16d390f0e443bfdffc7

Comment: Haven't thought of that, was looking for Jupyter cell magic... no luck there though.

Comment: @EvgeniyaTveritinova What do you pass in place of `op` while calling `tf_print`?

Comment: @Reutzesen the operation you want the printing attached to. Normally you attach it to some calculation, "op" and print the tensor belonging to it [op] but there's nothing stopping you to attach the operation to something else completely like op500 and still printing [op].

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. Run the py file from the python command line and you'll see what's inside tf. Print ().

Answer (score 0):

I've found that

```
print("foo = " + str(foo.eval()))
```

(where foo is your tensor) works just fine.